# Update PHP in the terminal

Tags: php, wamp

The `php -v` command gives me this:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2019 15:10:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

My wamp server is configured on PHP 7.4.9.

So why am I using version 5.6.40?
What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at PATH environment variable. Probably it's pointing to php5.6 dir

Comment: Yes thank you Felippe !

Comment: The PATH should NOT be pointing at any version of PHP in WAMPServer.. WAMPServer itself does not set the PATH for any reason